# Sidebar glitches on Markdown page

Tags: bug, sidebar, scrolling

On a page like [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), after scrolling for a little while, the sidebar will suddenly fling to the bottom of the screen and remain fixed:

[image]